Spring Security in a JavaFX desktop application
I have written a desktop application with Java and JavaFX.
I have Handled Roles with if and else. Likewise, I want to add sprig security to the project for authentication and authorization.
Also, this project is not a spring boot application or a web application.
How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.
I have used Spring Security for Spring Boot and web applications before.

I am not sure but you can use as jar these dependencies (security or etc.) you should add as jar in your project

Spring Security is for web security. Why do you need an authentification for desktop application? Even if you break it to start with How to implement java Authentication in desktop application.
